# iPad: How to handle multiple popovers regarding human guidelines?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I haven't notice an issue in my iPad App, where two popovers are visible at once. Because of that, my App got rejected with this comment:

> The iPad Human Interface Guidelines state that only one popover element should be visible onscreen at a time. In your application, the user can display two popovers at the same time. See the attached screenshot.

First of all, I would move the settings button to the right-side in the new version, but what if News popover is open and I tab the settings button -- what is expected behavior regarding their human guidelines? 1. Should I dismiss the News popover before I present the settings popover or 2. could I just do nothing, since the other popover is active?

I strongly guess that the first is right, but I would like to do it right this time. Thank you.

[image: Multiple popovers]

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114476/popover-inside-a-popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Apple's Interface Guidelines:

> Avoid providing a “dismiss popover” button. A popover should close automatically when its presence is no longer necessary.

If a user taps the "Settings" button, then assume the user would like the settings to be viewable and dismiss the first popover.  Visa Versa for the other button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should simply dismiss the news popover before the settings are shown.