# How to open UIPopover Controller from another UIPopover Controller?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

How i can open one Popover Controller from another Popover Controller in iPad?I want some idea on this please share your valuable thoughts.

Comment: You want to have two popover controllers on the screen? Or to simply open another popover from a button or action inside another popover?

Comment: I want 2 popover at a time and one should open from another

Comment: You simply present the second one just like you presented the first one... However, this is not allowed by Apple, read here more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119292/855738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning on submitting it in the App Store, I wouldn't bother.  It will almost certainly get rejected during the review process for violating the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html).

However, if you are wanting this for yourself personally OR to be published using an Enterprise license, then you would just present the second popover from the first popover.  Be careful, as you need to dismiss it from the view that presented it (delegate method).  Also take into account the HIG deemed this wrong for a reason.  Not saying that the HIG is ALWAYS correct (sometimes a particular process needs to do things differently), but when you go against Apple's rules about how things should look and feel, you really need to have a good reason.  All that being said, if this isn't destined for the App Store, then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer actually i have seen one of the apple store Application that's why i am planning to implement this functionality but now i have changed my thoughts. thanks for your guidelines.